# Ruby operator "+" behavior varies depending on spacing in code?

Tags: ruby, unary-operator

I came across a bit of an oddity (am using Ruby 1.9.1). Case scenario being:

```
class D
    ...
    def self.d6
        1+rand(6)
    end
    ...
end

v = D::d6+2    # fine and dandy
v = D::d6 +2   # in `d6': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
v = D::d6 + 2  # fine and dandy
```

Why the "+2" in second case is treated as being "positive 2" and not an "addition of 2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` same as the `-` in ruby are overloaded in order to make the syntax look nice.

When there is no space the Ruby parser recognizes the `+` as the method which is called on the result of `d6` which is an `Integer`.
Same goes for the version with space before and after the `+`.

However: In the operator precedence in Ruby `+` as a unary operator is defined before `+` as a binary operator (as is often the case in other languages as well).

Therefore if there is a space before the `+` but not after it, the Ruby Parser will recognize it as `d6(+2)` which fits the error message.

Comment: Ah, so it's intentional difference, more or less. After thinking your answer over for a moment, am starting to see why - although at first it felt that it'd been more natural if all those three cases would've been treated being just a variation of one and the same.

Comment: Actually operator precendence plays no role here, the interpretation of `+` occurs during [lexical analysis](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L7376-L7403).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the correction :-) - Either way: it is on purpose